# Annoying cryptic clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

I found an old puzzle, torn out of a newspaper, it looked like.

> Google is your friend. (4)

It's a clue that has bothered me.

I **think** I might know the correct answer, but there are plenty of folks here better at this than I am.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Edit: I've have been asked to post what I think the answer **might** be, in spoiler space.

My guess assumes we're looking for a 4 -letter word that would mean "friend," but might **also**, somehow, mean "Google."

I have two possibles, hidden in spoiler space in rot-13:

> Crre be Puhz

If you looked, have any thoughts?  I don't really like either of those . . .

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling.SE. I have edited your question to emphasize on the clue, feel free to edit it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the word "find" is somehow contained in FrIeND, but I can't see any indication to remove the "re". Find would be a good match for the definition "google", though. Do you have any crossing letters?

Comment: Hehe .. it actually is a website: http://www.giyf.com/

Comment: @MikeLimburg I'm partial to [lmgtfy.com](http://bfy.tw/Em0g) myself.

Comment: @feelinferrety Nice one!

Comment: @m oehm This was an old puzzle I had in a drawer.  I had a long drive, , and wrote out a few of the clues on index cards to think about while driving.  This was one of them.  I never got back to the puzzle, and don't know any of the cross letters.  It was printed on newsprint, so I suppose there to have been an editor who knew what he/she was doing, but I can't swear to that.  For a while, on UseNet, I put CC I thought were interesting as a tag line.  This was one, and must date back at least to Jan of 2012.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears the spacebar may have been broken on the setters keyboard.

If you re-typeset the clue as:

> Go_ogle is your friend  (This is permissible, as one of the golden rules is IGNORE ALL PUNCTUATION!)

the answer becomes a simple double definition:

> PEER (Go ogle - look) and (friend)

Comment: Hmmm. What is the meaning of "go" then? Usually, both parts of the split word in such lift-and-separate clue are used. ("Indeed" to place something in DEED or "drawback" for WARD, for example.)

Comment: Go ogle = An imperative form meaning PEER (The GO is not necessary, but it's presence doesn't change anything.)

Comment: This definitely seems like a good candidate for the intended answer, though when a clue requires a word to be split in two like that it normally matches how the word naturally breaks (and it's a bit questionable as a cluing device even then)

Comment: I disagree that "ignore all punctuation" means "you're free to introduce word breaks wherever you want". A word break isn't punctuation. The point is that "to google" means "to search", i.e., to look, i.e., to peer.

Comment: Look at @MOehm 's comment.  He includes two well established examples where this is done.

Comment: Splitting words is questionable and disliked by many, and when done at all is done on natural syllable boundaries where the word formation itself argues for looking at the word piecewise. There are a handful of words that this gets done with, most of which are well known, dubious though the practice may be. None of that would argue in favor of splitting Google this way, and if that were the mechanic here I think a lot of cryptic solvers would have a great deal of vitriol to spray around over it :)

Comment: In any event, the rationale for such splitting  ̵h̵a̵i̵r̵s̵ ̵ words is not "ignore all punctuation", so don't take that rule as free license to split words or join words willy-nilly. Cryptics that required such shenanigans wouldn't be very favorably received.

Comment: A peer is not quite a friend either. But the answer rings true

Comment: @MOehm Perhaps "Google" is a misprint for "Goggle". Goggle means to look with wide open eyes and can work as a definition for peer. The clue then works as a double definition and the sentence also plays with the fact that goggle is both a noun and a verb ("the eyepiece is your friend").

Comment: @HughMeyers "Google" means "search", which is very close to "peer", so I don't think there's any need to suppose a misprint.

Comment: "Google" and "peer" can both be used approximately synonymously with "search" but that doesn't mean they're viable synonyms for each other in a clue. In fact they both refer to pretty distinct meanings of "search" ('perform a web search' vs 'look closely'). If that's what's intended then the writer of the clue allowed themselves quite a bit too much licence in order to get a clue that's an existing phrase.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I think Alphabet may dispute your view that Google means search. Google is a trademark and I suspect Alphabet wouldn't want it going the same way as xerox and escalator (a process amusingly known as genericide) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks for a fun read, for *some* definition of "fun".

Comment: I'm not sure about PEER. That word, at least in my mind, equates to equal rather than friend (it *may* be a friend but it's not a requirement - think twelve of your peers on a jury - it would be nice if they were all your friends, at least if you were the defendant but that would be rare and unintended). My first thought was ALLY but, unfortunately, I can think of no secondary path from the clue to there.

Answer (score 4):

This obviously isn't the intended answer but how about

> BING

since

> Bing is a search engine like Google, and (Chandler) Bing is your and everyone else's Friend

Comment: If you're making this jump, then why not consider Bing and Google friends (due to both being search engines), as opposed to pulling a Chandler Bing reference out of thin air?

Comment: if the clue were "Google a Friend" this would be a good answer.

Comment: I would posit that Bing and Google are in fact mortal enemies rather than friends :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't the answer be:

> HINT

Because:

> HINT's letters can be found in **THINK** as provided by OP

And:

> Google is famous for giving hints (guessing what you try to mean) if you'd type in letters in the search bar.

Additional:

> The title says "Annoying cryptic clue", which is a synonym for a hint.

Comment: That's not how cryptics work.  The answer, once known, will be unambiguous from the clue.

Comment: It is definitely worth a longshot. If it ain't the answer, we can exclude it.

Comment: No, I wasn't trying to be cutesy.  I **believe** I may know the answer, but the puzzle is long gone.  I have no hope of finding what happened to it, or finding the answer key.  I just remember this one clue in particular that stuck in my mind, and I never did really figure it out.  So there are **no** other "clues" in this **anywhere.**. It's just "Google is your friend. (4)". That's **it**, and that's **all.**

Comment: It was worth a shot, thanks for the information. I'll perhaps give it another try

Comment: Yeah.  Your first try was kinda thin. <eg>

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be

> PEER

Reasoning:

> As a verb, peer means to look or search (i.e., to google); as a noun, it means an equal, which is close enough to a friend.

This is similar reasoning to [Chris Cudmore's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56500/2023) but without the dubious insertion of a space into the clue.

Comment: By that reasoning, I would say "CHUM" is just as good, since "to chum" is to throw out a little, in the hopes of getting more in return, similar to typing into a Google search bar.  Since by that reasoning, PEER and CHUM both work equally well, I'd have to say I prefer Chris' answer based on "Go Ogle," as it justifies PEER, but excludes CHUM.

Comment: I think CHUM is rather tenuous, though I follow your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a wild guess (as it is mentioned as cryptic clue)

> it could be **F** R **I** E **ND** (that is *FIND* and that is what  Google is used for (even the verb Googled interchangeably used for finding))

Comment: But what clues the dropping of RE?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore The nature of cryptic clues is to find _within_ the provided words/phrases, as genreally understood. So the clue for dropping of RE is to link/relate Google with the given limited words, I thought.

Comment: The wordplay is always unambiguous (when solved).   So there needs to be language such as "Not Regarding" to tell the solver to drop the RE.

Comment: This is a cryptic clue, meaning it follows specific rules (detailed in the [tag:cryptic-clues] tag wiki). Can you explain how this interpretation follows those rules?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an annoying clue, it's perhaps allusive. "Google is your friend" is actually a thing that people say, so maybe the answer is:

> MEME

Just a guess.

On the other hand, if the clue was "Apple is your friend" then the answer might be:

> A PAL

Comment: This is a good idea, but I don't think it's likely.  This is from years ago.  I used it at one point as a tag line to posts on UseNet, so I went looking to see when that was. I found one dated January 4, 2012, so it has to date before that, and I'm not sure the word "MEME" was commonly used as we use it now that far back.  Also found a page (In Hebrew, I think) that shows this.  I tried running it through GTranslate, and it showe "arrayed on a spectrum" (in quotes, just as I have typed it) in what looks to be a search bar.  I don't know **what** to do with that. (https://tinyurl.com/y7pmp9ov)

Comment: The word was invented in 1976 by Richard Dawkins, and in its current usage (lolcats etc) has been around since I would hazard mid-1990s. Odd discovery.

Answer (score -2):

It might be

> [YOLO (You Only Login Once)](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dashlane-google-you-only-login-once-yolo-nitin-malhotra)

Probably because

> you can use Google's feature to alleviate the hassle of remembering passwords.

Comment: This is a cryptic clue, meaning it follows specific rules (detailed in the [tag:cryptic-clues] tag wiki). Can you explain how this interpretation follows those rules?

Comment: @Deusovi When I wrote the answer, the tags were different. This might be obsolete unless I find some logic to still fit it in there. Let me try

Answer (score -2):

Let's give this thing a second try.
What about...

> HITS

Because Google

> Will give you a lot of hits when looking something up. It is your friend!

Besides,

> "Your friend" is a musician named Taryn Blake Miller, who obviously scored a few hits (songs).

Comment: Why is that a better answer for "your friend"  than Hank Aaron?  I'm not quite following . . .

Comment: "Your friend" is the artist name of mr. Miller. Google "Your friend", he'll be your first hits. ;)

Comment: This is a cryptic clue, meaning it follows specific rules (detailed in the [tag:cryptic-clues] tag wiki). Can you explain how this interpretation follows those rules?

Comment: Just giving thoughts. I see the answer is there already, so I'm retreating :)

Answer (score -2):

What if the answer was 'ally'. A friend can be formally referred to as an ally and is very commonly used when referencing friendships between countries.

Furthermore, in the eyes of war, an ally is someone who gives you intelligence or supplies to aid your efforts. Google would be an ally in this sense because it supplies you intelligence or knowledge on things you search for

Comment: Please read the tag wiki  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/cryptic-clues/info